# Add image before link in woocommerce plugin

Tags: plugins

I am working with woocomerce plugin. My woocomerce product display like this:

```
<div class="product-box">
   <a href="http://localhost/ebhajipala_latest/shop/health/veg14/">
       <img class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" width="150" height="150" alt="download" src="http://localhost/ebhajipala_latest/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/download-150x150.jpg">
   </a>
</div>
```

But now I want to remove image tag from  anchor tag. And use like this:

```
<img class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" width="150" height="150" alt="download" src="http://localhost/ebhajipala_latest/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/download-150x150.jpg">
<a href="http://localhost/ebhajipala_latest/shop/health/veg14/"></a>
```

So what should I have to do?
My archive_product.php page code is :

```
 <div class="pr_name">
    <h2>Products</h2>
</div>
<div class="pr_slider">
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[wpb-latest-product title="Latest Product"]'); ?>
</div>
```

```
    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

        <!--<h1 class="page-title"><?php //woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>-->

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' ); ?>
    <div class="pr_name">

</div>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
        ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
                        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );                   

             endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
        ?>

    <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

        <?php wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_after_main_content hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_sidebar hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */
    //do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
?>
```

Comment: post the code, that you did try. where you are stuck?

Comment: @sohan i have edited my code now check it and give me answer.

Comment: Support for specific plugin is off-topic here. Please consult at related support or stackoverflow.com with tag `WooCommerce`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution: find your `content-product.php` find the below code

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
        ?>

        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
        ?>

    </a>
```

move the a tag like:

```
<?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
        ?>

        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
        ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
```

Note: Use the customization in your theme/woocommerce directory otherwise changes will undo if plugin got update.

Hence above changes may depend on the theme you are using. if your theme already have woocommerce do changes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you have `wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );` so you have to look in the file `content-product.php`